# Having issues with scope of driver class/class in Java

Tags: java

I made a `Sphere` class that contains a handful of functions. I then made a `MultiSphere` class that acts as a "driver class". I put the `Sphere` class in the driver class (is that how you are supposed to use classes/driver classes?) and now it looks like I am getting an error about trying to access the `Sphere.diameter` variable because it is going through the `Multisphere` class first.

My IDE says

```
Multisphere.this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

and I get the error

```
non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

when I try to create a new instance of my `Sphere` class on the last line:

```
Sphere circle = new Sphere(15);
```

Complete code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class MultiSphere {

    public class Sphere {
        // Instance Variables
        double diameter;

        // Constructor Declaration of Class
        private Sphere(double diameter) {
            this.diameter = diameter;
        }

        private double getDiameter() {
            System.out.printf("Diameter is %f \n", diameter);
            return diameter;
        }

        // Allows user to modify the diameter variable
        private double setDiameter() {
            System.out.print("Enter the diameter for the sphere: \n");
            this.diameter = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
            return diameter;

        }

        private void Volume() {
            double radius = diameter / 2;
            double volume = (4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3)) / 3;
            System.out.printf("The volume of the sphere is: %f \n", volume);

        }

        private void surfaceArea() {
            double radius = diameter / 2;
            double surfaceArea = 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
            System.out.printf("The surface area is: %f \n", surfaceArea);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Hello World");
         Sphere circle = new Sphere(15);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Sphere` is a non-static inner class. This means that you need an instance of `MultiSphere` in order to access it:

```
MultiSphere ms = new MultiSphere();
Sphere s = new ms.Sphere();
```

Alternatively, you can just make the `Sphere` class static:

```
public static class Sphere {
```

Finally, you can put the classes into two files named `MultiSphere.java` and `Sphere.java`, respectively. Personally, I prefer this.

Comment: I think making an instance of `MultiSphere` is the way to go here. If I made `Sphere` class static, then I wouldn't be able to create multiple instances of it with different `diameter` variables for each instance right?

Comment: Hmm, when I added an instance of `Multisphere`, it gave me an error saying `ms` does not exist even though there is now an instance of it created from `MultiSphere ms = new MultiSphere();`

Comment: Okay, I think this whole nested class thing was not working for me so I undid that and just defined `Sphere` class as `class Sphere` instead of `public class Sphere`. That solved my problems

Answer (score -2):

you have to change the private scope to public.

```
    private Sphere(double diameter) {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }
```

Like that

```
    public Sphere(double diameter) {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }
```

it does not make sense to have a private constructor unless you call it in the same class.